# Another tableview reload problem

Tags: ios, reload, tableview

I'm loading a TableView from Core Data and it works like a charm. The data contains two fields: Category and Distance. The initial load of the table uses an array with the objects sorted based on Distance. I have a button in the Navigation Bar that I want the user to use to toggle between a Distance-sorted view (the default) and a Category-sorted view. My code for the toggle is:

```
-(void)toggleView {

    NSString *baseItem = @"Proximity View"; 
    NSString *currTitle = self.title; 
    NSComparisonResult result;
    result = [baseItem compare:currTitle];

    if (result == 0) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Category View",@"Categories");
        tpData = tpDataCat; //tpDataCat is an array sorted by Category
        [self.tblView reloadData];
    } else {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Proximity View",@"Distances");
        tpData = tpDataDist; //tpDataDist is an array sorted by Distance
        [self.tblView reloadData];
    }

    [baseItem release];
    [currTitle release];
}
```

When I click the toggle button and fire `toggleView, the app just crashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be releasing baseItem and currTitle.

I would recommend reading the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html); it's an excellent document that can provide background on the appropriate ownership of objects and when releasing would be required.